# Regex match for optional file extension

Tags: python, regex, url, python-2.7

I'm extracting portions of URLs from text using a regular expression in Python. The URLs I'm looking for are from a limited set of patterns so it feels like I should just able to handle them in a regex. What I'm trying to extract is the first portion of the file name (**"some.file.name" in all the examples below**), which can include dots, letters and digits.

These are the sorts of forms the URL can take:

```
http://www.example.com/some.file.name.html
http://www.example.com/some.file.name_foo.html
http://www.example.com/some.file.name(123).html
http://www.example.com/some.file.name_foo(123).html
http://www.example.com/some.file.name
http://www.example.com/some.file.name_foo
http://www.example.com/some.file.name(123)
http://www.example.com/some.file.name_foo(123)
```

I think I'm pretty much there with this regex:

```
http://www\.example\.com/([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)(_[a-z]+)?(\(\d+\))?(\.html)?
```

But it includes the ".html" in the match when the URL is like the first one in the list. Is there any way of stopping this or is it a fundamental limitation of regular expressions?

I'm quite happy to remove the extension in code as it will always be the same and will never be valid as part of the file name, but it would be cleaner to do it as part of the regex match.

**Edit:**

I should emphasise that these URLs are in bodies of text. I can't make any guarantees about whether there are characters before or after them or what those characters might be. I think it's safe to assume that they won't be numbers, letters, underscores or dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are matched **greedy** by default.

Try this regexp:

```
^http://www\.example\.com/([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+?)(_[a-z]+)?(\(\d+\))?(\.html)?$
```

Notice the extra `?` added to not capture the `.html` in the first part. It makes the first group capture *as little as neccessary to match*, instead of as much as possible to match. Without the `?`, the `.html` will be included in the first group, as the other groups are optional, and greedy matching tries to match as "early" as possible.

P.S. Also note that I anchored the regexp using `^` and `$` to always match the full line.

Comment: Unfortunately as all the groups after the file name are optional using `?` here will simply give me the first letter of the file name, as there's nothing to "pull" the regex over the end of the URL.

Comment: My next thought was to use a word boundary (`\b`) to pull the regex to the end of the URL. Of course that doesn't work as `.` counts as a word boundary.

Comment: That is why I added the `$` sign, too. Did you copy that as well?
In some languages, "matching" implies `^` and `$` as opposed to "searching" which is open ended. I prefer the explicit way with `^` and `$` though.
But I havn't tested whether the first question mark is enough to make the optional group at the end stronger. But it should be "greedy optional"?

Comment: That would work if I was just working with URLs on their own, sadly I'm extracting them from bodies of text.

Comment: And yes, "greedy optional" is a pretty accurate description of what I'm after.

Comment: Then define a separator that properly ends the URL instead. E.g. `(?:$| )`

Comment: Ah, of course :) `(?:$|[^a-zA-z0-9._])` seems to work in my case. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the .html extension as a non-capturing group:

```
http://www\.example\.com/([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)(_[a-z]+)?(\(\d+\))?(?=(\.html)?)
```

Comment: Sadly that's not the issue here. My problem is that the ".html" is being included in the first group, not that it's being captured in its own group.

Comment: Ok, try a suffix group then: (?=(\.html)?) at the end instead of ?:

Comment: Trying this out at http://burkeware.com/software/regex_playground.html still includes `.html` in the case of the first example. Could this be something that's language dependent?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you don't care about the file extension. You just want to extract file names.

Try this one:

```
http://www\.example\.com/([\w]+.[\w]+.[\w()]+)
```

In PHP, I used preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches), it returned something like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.example.com/some.file.name
            [1] => http://www.example.com/some.file.name_foo
            [2] => http://www.example.com/some.file.name(123)
            [3] => http://www.example.com/some.file.name_foo(123)
            [4] => http://www.example.com/some.file.name
            [5] => http://www.example.com/some.file.name_foo
            [6] => http://www.example.com/some.file.name(123)
            [7] => http://www.example.com/some.file.name_foo(123)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => some.file.name
            [1] => some.file.name_foo
            [2] => some.file.name(123)
            [3] => some.file.name_foo(123)
            [4] => some.file.name
            [5] => some.file.name_foo
            [6] => some.file.name(123)
            [7] => some.file.name_foo(123)
        )

)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

A more generic match where the file name and its extension could be *anything*:

```
^(.+?)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)?$
```

This non-greedily matches at least one char, then finds a period (`.`) and zero or more letters or digits or underscores (i.e. any char allowed in an extension) before the end of the name.

Test input with all possible file name / extension cases:

```
name.txt
name.tar.gz
.hidden
period.
plain name
```

Output for the first matched substring:

```
name
name.tar
.hidden
period
plain name
```

It's questionable, however, whether the ".hidden" file is an extension or not. If you want to see it as a name

If you want to allow any char (except period and space, of course) in the extension, use this instead:

```
^(.+?)(\.[^ .]*)?$
```